# How to pass data to another web forms in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

First web form:

```
public partial class Product : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
//------------------------data variable------------------------------//
    public static double pheight;
    public static decimal pweight;

 //other code
    }
```

Second web form:

```
public partial class Result : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //------------------------------------Offset variable------------------------------------------------------
    double oHeight = Product.pheight;    **//how to grab data here?**
    int oWeight = Product.pweight;      **//how to grab data here?**

    //display data function
    private void data_display()
    {
        lblName.Text = "Name: " + Product.Pname;     **//how to grab data here?**
        //display username
        lblID.Text = "ID        : " + Product.UserID;     **//how to grab data here??**
```

The code 'Product' is incorrect. Does anyone know how to solve this? Appreciate your help.

Comment: You don'0t call other pages, when the page has been executed it's destroyed, if you want to pass data between executions you must store them in a session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a previous web form from the current web form. However, there are different ways of passing information between web forms.

- You can use the QueryString
- You can use the Session
- You can store data in Cookies
- You can persist data in a database

Every option has pros and cons

Comment: It would have been better if you can provide some examples of each of the case than simple name / theory. Can even use Http Body for data transfer or Cache at the Application server